# Can I autoscale Kind : Pod?

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling, kubernetes-pod, hpa

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
 name: testingHPA

spec:
 scaleTargetRef:
   apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
   kind: Deployment
   name: my_app
 minReplicas: 3
 maxReplicas: 5
 targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 85
```

Above is the normal hpa.yaml structure, is it possible to use kind as a pod and auto scale it ??

Comment: Short answer, no

Comment: You can not use pod kind and autoscale it. HPA is created for autoscaling pods. Why you don't want to use HPA?

Comment: I wanted to use that because , whenever I delete pods they were getting created again as they are under deployment controller. Is there any policy that will stop pods which are under deployment from getting restart ? .. as in some scenario we might need to do that !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already pointed by others, it is not possible to set `Pod` as the `Kind` object as the target resource for an HPA.

The [document describes HPA](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) as:

> The Horizontal Pod Autoscaler automatically scales the number of Pods
> in a replication controller, deployment, replica set or stateful set
> based on observed CPU utilization (or, with custom metrics support, on
> some other application-provided metrics). Note that Horizontal Pod
> Autoscaling does not apply to objects that can't be scaled, for
> example, DaemonSets.

The document also described how the algorithm is implemented at the backend as:

```
desiredReplicas = ceil[currentReplicas * ( currentMetricValue / desiredMetricValue )]
```

and since the `Pod` resource does not have the replicas field as part of its spec therefore we can conclude that the same is not supported for auto scaling using the HPA.

Answer (score 2):

A single Pod is only ever one Pod. It does not have any mechanism for horizontal scaling because it is that mechanism for everything else.